# I want to make sure people are not direct linking to my Amazon 3S files

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3

I have a freebie site (Wordpress) where I share graphics and such. But it seems I have more downloads than I do visitors. How can I make sure people are not using my links elsewhere. Can I restrict the links only to my site?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't . If browsers couldn't download resources than the users wouldn't see them :) So only you can do is watermark your graphics, or not post it at all :)